# Spring WebMVC with Data and Couchbase - Error creating bean when trying to inject as service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I just started to work with Spring. I followd some tutorials to create a Spring Web MVC project which works. It is a simple project which displays some information as website using thymeleaf.

Now I wanted to add a couchbase database for storing data, I already worked with couchbase for simple .Net Apps. So I followed the tutorial on the official couchbase blog to create a service for the connection to couchbase. [Couchbase with Spring-Boot and Spring Data](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/)

But when I try to autowire the service I get the following error message:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 70ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
[main] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xplorg.model.BuildingService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
[main] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xplorg.model.BuildingService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

As far as I understand the message, found Spring the repository but it does not qualify as autowire candidate.

My WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.project.controller")
@ComponentScan("com.xplorg.model")
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.model"})
public class MvcWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // Code for generating templateEngine/Resolver ...
}
```

My controller (here I try to autowire the service, not sure if it is the correct place, causes the exception):

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    private int count = 0;

    @Autowired
    private BuildingService buildingService;
    // This line causes the exception

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Hello World");
        return "index";
    }

    // Some more mapping no use of service
}
```

My BuildingService:

```
public interface BuildingService {

    Building save(Building building);

    Building findById(String buildingId);

    List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId);

    Building findByCompanyAndAreaId(String companyId, String areaId);

    List<Building> findByCompanyIdAndNameLike(String companyId, String name, int page);

    List<Building> findByPhoneNumber(String telephoneNumber);

    Long countBuildings(String companyId);

}
```

My BuildingServiceImpl:

```
@Service("BuildingService")
public class BuildingServiceImpl implements BuildingService {

    @Autowired
    private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyId(companyId);
    }

    public List<Building> findByCompanyIdAndNameLike(String companyId, String name, int page) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyIdAndNameLikeOrderByName(companyId, name, new PageRequest(page, 20))
                .getContent();
    }

    @Override
    public Building findByCompanyAndAreaId(String companyId, String areaId) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyAndAreaId(companyId, areaId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Building> findByPhoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
        return buildingRepository.findByPhoneNumber(telephoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public Building findById(String buildingId) {
        return buildingRepository.findById(buildingId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Building save(Building building) {
        return buildingRepository.save(building);
    }

    @Override
    public Long countBuildings(String companyId) {
        return buildingRepository.countBuildings(companyId);
    }
}
```

The order classes are simple copied from the tutorial.

Project sturcture:

```
src/main/java
    com.project
        config
            MvcWebApplicationInitializer
            MvcWebConfig
        controller
            IndexController
        model
            Area
            Building
            BuildingRepository
            BuildingService
            BuildingServiceImpl
```

**EDIT**

At the end of the error message the following line stands, could that mean I am missing a dependency?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
```

**EDIT 2**

After trying different approaches and reading more about Spring/Couchbase and Autowired, I now get the exception that `No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available`. The whole exception looks like this:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
[main] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildingRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingRepository': 'buildingRepository' depends on missing bean 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
[main] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildingRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingRepository': 'buildingRepository' depends on missing bean 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
```

Comment: I think that adding "com.project.model" to your componentScan should fix the problem

Comment: Added a second ComponentScan for the model package but it still does not work.

Comment: Post the BuildingService code!

Comment: I added the BuildingService code and the implementing of it.